# Is it possible to disable the login dialog box of Kali Linux?

Tags: kali-linux, gdm, autologin

For example, I need my Kali Desktop to be logged in freely, without the use of any password.

That is, I should not see the following Login dialog box after the boot up.

How to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure your `gdm3` , `PAM` for `autologin` :

Edit  `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` file.

```
# Enable automatic login for user
[daemon]
AutomaticLogin=username
AutomaticLoginEnable=True
```

Put the following `pam` configuration into `/etc/pam.d/gdm-password`:

```
auth sufficient pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup nopasswdlogin
```

Then create user and group `nopasswdlogin`.